# R - Serializing function leads to very large object

Tags: r, serialization, ggplot2, ggmap

I've encountered an issue where serializing a ggplot object leads to a very large raw vector:

```
library(ggmap)
>raw <- serialize(ggmap(get_map('Europe',zoom=4)))
>object.size(raw)
122917968 bytes
```

I've narrowed this down to a single function being serialized that's approx ~120MB
What causes this explosion in size? How do I investigate further? Is it related to the function's environment?